# Remove input from an output stream

Tags: c++, vector, iostream, ostream

I want to use `std::copy` and `std::ostream_iterator` to print out the string within a `vector` as a coma separated list between parenthesis. So I have to deal with the issue of removing the `", "` after the last element.

I have tried [this](http://ideone.com/78kJEw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("c");

    std::stringstream os;
    os << '(';
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, ", "));
    os.seekp(-2, std::ios_base::cur);
    os << ')';

    std::cout << os.str() << ".";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(a, b, c) .
         ^
```

But the output I get has an extra white space character after the closing parenthesis, because `seekp` just moves the writing position but doesn't remove the written characters.

Is there a way to remove that last character or write an EOF?

Comment: Are you open to alternative solutions, or is fiddling with the stream the only option you'll accept?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I'm open

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about not writing the extra `", "` at the end in the first place...

```
if(!v.empty())
{
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, ", "));
   os << v.back();
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this solution works for `vector` but not for `set`, for which I also want to implement an analogous printing function. Since performance is not an issue, I will just create a temporary `vector` from the `set` and reuse the `vector` printing function.

Comment: @AntonioPérez: Replace `v.end()-1` with `std::prev(v.end())`, and `v.back()` with `*std::prev(v.end())`, and it works fine for sets.

Comment: Still a shame :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817038/remove-input-from-an-output-stream/19817187?noredirect=1#comment29465041_19817274

Comment: @AntonioPérez: `std::prev` is an extremely simple function which you can implement yourself, or simply implement the logic inline.  Just create an iterator from `v.end()`, and decrement it once.

Answer (score 2):

You are not just removing the characters when you use `seekp`, you are setting the current cursor.  Your next statement will overwrite that character, but you still have the subsequent characters in the buffer already.  There are a couple of ways to deal with that:

Don't output the full pattern:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << '(';
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, ", "));
if (v.size() > 1) // or (!v.empty())
    os << *(v.end() - 1) << ')';
```

This will print all but the last character of your vector with the pattern (the extra ", " combination will be avoided entirely).

Alternatively, you can reset the buffer manually:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << '(';
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, ", "));
std::string t = os.str();
t.resize(t.size() - 2);
os.str() = t;
os << ')';
```

Or, perhaps a more uniform solution (if you are not opposed to not using copy):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << '(';
if (v.size() > 1) // or (!v.empty())
    os << v.front();

std::for_each(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), [&](const std::string& s)
{
    os << ", " << s;
});
os << ")";
```

Comment: Your last proposal looks very nice. It's a shame that my compiler doesn't support C++11 features.

Comment: You can do it in a functor or write your own loop and it wouldn't look too much different (and would compile in C++98/03).

Comment: The second proposal works only for `stringstream`, not for `ostream`. I just used `stringstream`in the example, but my actual code covers the general case using `ostream`.

Comment: @AntonioPérez You mean the one that resets the string?  Yes, that is specific to `ostringstream`.  Personally, I would recommend the third method.  In general, I try to avoid writing extra characters to a string and then fix it later.  It just makes the code less readable.